# How can I receive file in Python over HTTP?

Tags: python, http

I need receive some files over HTTP and save them.

How can I do this on Python **without** frameworks like Django or Flask?

Comment: By receiving files do you mean downloading them from a server or being uploaded them?

Comment: Are you creating a HTTP server or client?

Answer (score 4):

Use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html). Example:

```
import urllib2
f = urllib2.urlopen("http://download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip")

with open("5MB.zip", "wb") as local_file:
    local_file.write(f.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

Django or Flask are for serving Web Applications. You just want to download something over http?

If you do, give urllib2 a try:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html

Sample Code here:
http://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html

Answer (score 1):

A good way is by using urllib. Make sure to parse the URL correctly.

```
import urllib
f = urllib.urlretrieve('http://audio.com/2010/mp3/goodSong.mp3','a.mp3')
```